# Scala: Given a TSV file, take the 1st two columns in each line and return the following: Array[Map[column_one:String, column_two:String]]

Tags: scala, dictionary, split, csv

Given a TSV file, take the 1st two columns in each line and return the following: Array[Map[column_one:String, column_two:String]]

Example File:

```
RowOneColumnOne RowOneColumnTwo RowOneColumnThree
RowTwoColumnOne RowTwoColumnTwo RowTwoColumnThree
```

Result:

```
[
  RowOneColumnOne: RowOneColumnTwo,
  RowTwoColumnTwo: RowTwoColumnTwo
]
```

Tried this:

```
var keyword = sc.textFile("hdfs://nameservice/some_tsv_file.txt")
val keywords = keyword.map(x => x.split("\t").take(2).toList ).collect().distinct
```

which returned a Array[List[String]]:

```
[
  [RowOneColumnOne, RowOneColumnTwo],
  [RowTwoColumnTwo, RowTwoColumnTwo]
]
```

Just not sure how to convert the List[String] to Map.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do what you want:

```
val keywords = keyword.map(x => x.split("\t").toList).collect {
  case y :: z :: _ => Map((y -> z))
}.distinct
```